# Playwright - Select Certificate in Java

Tags: javascript, java, certificate, playwright, client-certificates

I want to open a website using Playwright but when I try to navigate I receive the following:

> This site can’t provide a secure connection.
> Mywebsite.com didn’t accept your login certificate, or one may not have been provided. Try
> contacting the system admin. ERR_BAD_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_CERT

There is a general issue in Playwright - it does not support the client certificate out of the box, there has been an open issue for that ([#1799](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/1799)) for several years. Some people managed to find a workaround for that but in Javascript. I need to find a workaround for that in Java. The route option does not give me the ability to modify complex objects in the Request such as certificate, I tried using the addInitScript method in the browser context with the following but it didn't work.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const cert = fs.readFileSync('path/to/cert.cert');
const key = fs.readFileSync('path/to/key.key');
const passphrase = 'certPasswordValue';
const certOptions = { key, cert, passphrase };
const tls = require('tls');
const agent = new tls.Agent(certOptions);
window.fetch = (url, options) => {
  options.agent = agent;
  return window.origFetch(url, options);
};
```